# adding border only to direct child of table with a class

Tags: html, css, border

I want to add border to my specific table's td and th so i did like :

```css
table.borderedtable td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.borderedtable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class='borderedtable'>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>

        <tr>
          <td></td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

problem is the inside table also gets the border I want the border to be added only to td and th under the table with class. So i tried using direct child select `>` like below:

```css
table.borderedtable>tr>td,>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.borderedtable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class='borderedtable'>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>

        <tr>
          <td></td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Now I dont get any border

Comment: table.borderedtable>tr>td,>tr>th Is that comma meant to be there?

Comment: to separate `td` from `th` ?

Comment: Oh I know this one: The browsers inserts a <tbody> inside tables. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Regarding the comma I mentioned, the second part of your selector (`>tr>th`) will fail. That's why I suggested that the comma was a typo. I suspect what you want is: table.borderedtable>tbody>tr>td,table.borderedtable>tbody>tr>th

Comment: just as an FYI `a>b>c` is the same as `a > b > c`. The latter is way more readable.

Comment: when i used the tidy button it removed the space :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser automatically inserts a `<tbody>` element inside tables, so the `tbody` is the direct descendent of your table, not `tr`.

For instance, to select the first td inside a table you would do this:

```
table.borderedtable>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table.borderedtable>tbody>tr>td, table.borderedtable>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.borderedtable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: that is the reason for direct child i feel so dumb